# How to execute several jquery animate at the same time

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

Suppose I have two self-defined animate function which make up by origin jquery animate function:
one is shake function, shake from left to right and turn back in infinite loop:

```
var leftright = function (el) {
                var duration = 800;
                var interval = duration * 4;
                var shake = function () {
                    el.animate({'left': '-=15'  }, duration)
                        .animate({'left': '+=15'  }, duration)
                        .animate({'left': '+=15'  }, duration)
                        .animate({'left': '-=15'  }, duration)
                }

                shake();
                setInterval(function () {
                    shake();
                }, interval)
            }
```

then I defined a flash animate function for flash all the time:

```
    var flash = function (el) {
        var duration = 300;
        var interval = duration * 2;
        var f = function () {
            el.animate({'opacity': 0}, duration)
                .animate({'opacity': 1}, duration)                    
        }
        f();
        setInterval(function () {
            f();
        }, interval)
    }
```

I want the element execute the two animate at the same time, so I use queue:

```
            var que = $({});
            que.queue('leftright', function () {
                leftright($('#el'));    
            }).dequeue('leftright');

            que.queue('flash', function () {
                flash($('#el'));    
            }).dequeue('flash');
```

but they still execute the shake first and then execute the flash

How can I execute them at the same time?

Here is the demo:http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/SykMu/

Comment: I understand this will change the frequency of the flash, but have you considered just combining the functions into one? http://jsfiddle.net/SykMu/1/   I'm interested in seeing how this can be done the way you have it set up though I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: @eivers88:In this case, the demo you give to me is what I want, But if every I have different effect need combine to together, I need calculate them precisely,I need figure out css status in each second.It is better I just write a few effect function, pass the target element to them, the effect could execute together.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be done, after looking at the http://api.jquery.com/animate/ doc and other resources, the only way I see to animate multiple properties at the same time to the same element is to set them within the same `.animate()` function. Good luck though, please post the solution if you find one this is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

may be... http://jsfiddle.net/u7bgs

instead of this js:

```
var que = $({});
que.queue('leftright', function () {
   leftright($('#el'));    
}).dequeue('leftright');

que.queue('flash', function () {
   flash($('#el'));    
}).dequeue('flash');
```

to try it:

```
$('#parent').wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
leftright($('.wrapper:has(#parent)'));

flash($('#parent'));
```